# Alternatives to React refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following piece of code

```
<App>
    <SideBar />
    <MainView pages={this.state.pages} />
</App>
```

The App component is basically responsible for creating pages which is just an array of DOM canvas elements. However inside MainView, I had to make use of refs to insert elements into the DOM of MainView like this

```
componentWillReceiveProps(p, e) {
    let self = this;
    self.holder.current.innerHTML = "";
    p.pages.forEach(p => {
        self.holder.current.appendChild(p);
    })
}
```

I was expecting I would do something like this in MainView

```
render() {
    return (
            <div className="main-view-display" id="main-view-display">{this.props.pages.join('')}</div>
    )
}
```

but this certainly didn't work. Also I've been told that Refs might get deprecated. So what's the best way to pass on DOM elements to the child? I don't want the logic of creating canvas to go into the MainView because the MainView component is a dumb component. Putting the logic there might make it less usable

Comment: Could the person who told you that `Refs might get deprecated` provide a source for this claim? The [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) mentions no such thing.

Comment: so @HMR, refs are perfectly legible stuff in react

Comment: I would think so. The documentation would mention not to use it because of deprecation but it doesn't. A lot of production code would depend on this and unless someone can provide a trusted source saying you can't use I would use it.

Comment: HMR is right. Use refs - that's your best bet.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs - seems that the refs are deprecated now...

Comment: Refs are deprecated now. Is there a way we can make this question relevant again?